# IE8 message "The site you are about to shop will not earn you Contributed"

Tags: internet, internet-explorer-8, windows-explorer

So I recently opened an XML file on the local file system and got the following (very odd) message at the top of the page:

> The site you are about to shop will
>   not earn you Contributed. We suggest

The message is getting cropped off and auto-hides after about 20 seconds. It occurs anytime I open a local xml file.

What is this?

[image]

Comment: Probably an addon that got added in. I would check what addons you have turned on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What it is, it is not an [IE8 message](http://wiki.imacros.net/IE_Nags). So it is either from the xml file or an addon. Try starting IE8 in safe mode to rule out addons.

Comment: Turns out it was the Digsby Donates addon created by Freecause. Disabling the add-on got rid of the message. Very weird!